# Copying report fields in ms access report vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, ms-office

I want to create button that copies fields in a report which comes from a form but I cant figure how to write the VBA behind button in VBA . I am sure its pretty simple but cant figure it out. I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: This is not a site where users write code for you from scratch. Show some coding efforts on your side. Besides statements in the post are so general, that they make us guess what's really needed.

Answer (score -1):

To convert an Access 2007 form to a report, follow these steps:

```
Open the database containing the form.
Click the name of the form in the Navigation pane.
Click the Microsoft Office button.
Point to Save As and then click Save Object As.
Click in the Save "Form_Name" To text box and enter a name for your report.
Click the drop-down arrow in the As text box and select Report from the list, then click OK.
```

No VBA required.